# RCP Application/SWT Label BOLD

Tags: java, swt, rcp

It is a RCP application, you have a (a) LIST of Names, it is downloaded by means of a FOR loop.

That is to say they are Menu items and that they are located to the left of the screen with its respective layer (composite).

Now, this works, the difficulty / what is needed here is that when you double-click on an Item it receives a "SWT.BOLD" character and when you click on another Item, the previous one receives SWT.NONE and the chosen one SWT.BOLD. 
A highlighten ....

Here Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        final Label l1 = neueLabel(shell, "label "+i, i);
        l1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.button==1)
                    l1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 9, 
                               SWT.BOLD));
            }
        });
    }
```

Tanks

Comment: So what is your actual problem? What don't you understand how to do?

Comment: Yes Greg! The code does half. That is to say I click on an Item it is put BOLD and if I click on another one, the first one follows BOLD and the second one also. What I need is that when I click on an Item the previous one receives SWT.NONE and the current SWT BOLD.

Comment: how do I solve this?

Comment: You will have to remember the previous label and change the font back to the normal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your currently highlighted label and reset its font. Assuming your class has a `private Label current;` your overwritten method may look like

```
if (e.button == 1) {
    if (current != null)
        current.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 9, SWT.NONE));
    l1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 9, SWT.BOLD));
    current = l1;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear. So please [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)